# Add Orchard as sibling directory of module (existing MVC app)

Tags: module, orchardcms

I have an existing mvc app and a complicated directory structure the organization uses. I understand in order to combine the existing app into orchard, I would have to add it as a subdir in the Modules area. What I'm trying to do is do that virtually, so that the existing file structure can stay in place but yet orchard can find the code and treat it as a module.

For example, the existing structure looks like

-phoneapp
-phoneapp.test
-clientlib
-clientlib.test
-security
-security.test
-website
-website.test

And I want:

-phoneapp
-phoneapp.test
-clientlib
-clientlib.test
-security
-security.test
-website
-website.test

-orchard

is this possible to direct orchard to look outside it's own directory structure for it's module?

Answer (score 1):

Orchard is going to want to take over the routing for whatever site it lives on. You can install Orchard into a subdirectory as the base path by creating a virtual application directory in IIS and dropping the Orchard source in there.